# Need suggestions - SQL and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem I tried solving on my own, but didn't get far (tried different approaches but all of them ended up in a big wall of code, that eventually did not do what I needed). So I'm here asking for any advice, solution, code snippets you can offer. Thanks in advance!

I have an SQL db with tables PARTS, ASSEMBLIES and FORMULA. As names suggest assemblies are made out of parts but can also be made out of other assemblies. How assemblies are made is written in table FORMULA. In my application I can enter how many assemblies have been made (increase stock). But when I increase stock for an assembly, I need to decrease stock for corresponding parts and (sub)assemblies. For better understanding I'll illustrate this with an example;

PARTS

```
partID   partStock
  p1       100
  p2       100
  p3       100
```

ASSEMBLIES

```
assID    assStock
ass1        10
ass2        10
```

FORMULA

```
assID   parts   isAssembly  quantity
ass1     p1         no          1
ass1     p2         no          2
ass1     ass2       yes         1 
ass2     p3         no          2
```

Explanation of the table: `ass1` is assembled from 1x `p1` + 2x `p2` + 1x `ass2` (which is another assembly) and `ass2` is assembled from 2x `p3`

So when I increase stock of ass1 for 10 (this is not a problem, I can do it), I would also need to decrease stock for p1(10), p2(20), ass2(10). And if stock for ass2 would be <10, I'd need to decrease stock of p3(for a remaining number).

Does anyone even understand what I want to do here? :D

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you very much! Oh, and I'm writing my web app in C#. :)

EDIT: As it has been pointed out in comments, I firstly search for an idea (design pattern) how to accomplish this. Actual SQL queries and coding is not such a big problem.. If anyone has some helpful code, its a bonus. ;)

Comment: I believe I understand what you're saying but you're not asking a explicit question. You can do this is ASP.net and SQL. Are you looking for a design pattern to use for this app?

Comment: As Jon mentioned... Are you asking design patter, or how to query and handle the inventory adjustments.  I do understand and have actually done work with a manufacturer dealing with such assembly/sub-assembly systems...  BTW, love the abbreviated table name / column name aliases :)

Comment: yeah, I don't really know where to start :) I'm kind of a newbie in programming. I'm not asking for someone to write the code for me (not that I wouldn't be thankfull for some code snippets :P)...just some ideas, how could I acomplish it.

Comment: @DRapp , +1 LOL...i didnt notice that

Comment: lol, I actually did not notice it eather :D In real app there are different IDs and abbreavtions ;)

Comment: you probably need to start with Eric Evans' Domain Driven Design Book.

Comment: Does your Web App integrate with an ERP system like SAP or SYSPRO?

Comment: @Dirk No. It is a custom made app for some small private assembly bussiness (to track current stock of parts and assemblies).

Comment: @Cosmin ATM I'm kind of on a tight schedule. :) But I may read it in the future, it looks like an interesting read.

Comment: if time is a constraint just hack a quick stored proc that updates all you need and be done with it. I am not in favour of this type of solutions but it's your call. you'll have to pay the technical debt at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would start with merging the part and assembly tables, this makes your model and calculations a easier to understand. Especially since an assembly can be a part of an other assembly as well. It will probably also make other things like inventory overviews a lot easier.

Your tables could look like this:

**PARTS:**

```
partID, partStock, isAssembly
p1      100        false
p2      100        false
p3      100        false
ass1    10         true
ass2    10         true
```

**FORMULA**

```
partID, part, quantity
ass1    p1    1
ass1    p2    2
ass1    ass2  1
ass2    p3    2
```

Technically the 'isAssembly' field in the Parts table isn't required because a part is an assembly when there are formulas for it.

To update the stock when parts are assembled you can recursively update the stock of the additional parts that need to be build.

The pseudo code for 'building' assemblies will be roughly like this:

```
void UpdateStock(string partID, int count)
{
    formulas = "select * from FORMULA where partID = " + partID;
    foreach(formula in formulas)
    {
        subPart = "select * from PARTS where partID = " + formula.partID;
        subCount = count * formula.quantity;

        // Check for sufficient stock of this part
        shortage = (subPart.partStock - subCount) * -1;
        if(shortage > 0)
        {
            // When this part is an assembly we can try to 'build' more.
            if(subPart.isAssembly)
            {
                UpdateStock(formula.partID, shortage);
                // Note that when making more isn't possible
                // this will throw an error.
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise there simple isn't enough.
                throw Error("Not enough stock");
            }
        }
        // Once we get here there should be enough stock, 
        // either because there was enough in the first place
        // or because we made more. 
        subPart.partStock = subPart.partStock - subCount;
    }

    // Lastly increase the actual stock.
    part = "select * from PARTS where partID = " + partID;
    part.partStock = part.partStock + count;
}
```

You do need to make sure you don't save any changes to the database until the whole function is done, otherwise you might have decreased the stock on one part before the function fails because another part is out of stock.

Comment: I merged the tables and am working on making your suggested pseudo code to work for my problem. I think I'll manage. Only problem left is "Timeout Expired" exception I get when I call UpdateStock for the second time. Need to see, which connections are left open and close them...shouldn't take too long :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm reading, and your time constraints, a stored procedure may be best. How I would approach it is to create a temp table in the stored procedure of all elements at the first level of the assembly (along with type of an actual item vs a sub-assembly).  Then, you'll have to keep doing all the recursion manually until you get all sub-sub-sub assemblies.  I would try this routine with one of the more complex assemblies to ensure you get a combination of individual parts, and multiple sub-assemblies, and any that have sub-sub-assemblies, etc.

Keep the test version into an actual table so you can look at the results until you get all the tweaking done with how much inventory needs to be reduced or increased appropriately... THEN, once all looks good, then apply an update joined to this one table so its done as a single call and not in a nested "oops... missed that one" and mess up inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have totally understand what's your meanding.
I think use a CTE you can get all of the "PARTS" recursively, and do your increase and decrease operations in a DbTransaction.